# Re-establishing SSH without VNC, HDMI

Tags: ssh, pi-3b+, hdmi, vnc

My Raspi has suddenly stopped working with VNC viewer, HDMI, and SSH (which is enabled).
Before this happened, I connected via SSH, and added the Raspi to my home network as well as VNC viewer.
My only hope is to establish an SSH connection. I have the IP address of the pi, and didn't mess with any internet settings, but it is not responding to any pings or SSH.
I've already attempted to enable SSH again (in case it was off for some reason) via USB, but that has no effect (SSH is already enabled).

I really want to save my pi, but I have no idea how.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If HDMI isn't working than you have most likely bricked the Pi or corrupted the SD card so badly that the bootloader doesn't see it. You have tried to plug in a display via a working HDMI cable?

Comment: Bit baffled by the 'enabled via USB' note.  Can you explain a bit more?  Is there anyway you can check your router to see if the Pi has changed IP address?  If you have a spare SD card you can put Raspbian on to it(I normally use Lite as it's quicker) and see if the Pi works.

Answer (score -1):

1. how are you connecting raspberrypi to your network? ethernet or wifi check if that is working using `ifconfig`
2. now check if IP is static or manual in `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`
3. if static then check if your router IP is correct if manual then check `sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/supplicant` and your network SSID and password like [this link](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2017/04/manually-setting-up-pi-wifi-using-wpa_supplicant-conf/)

good luck!

Comment: **DO NOT** advise people to use deprecated commands or use old networking.

Comment: which ones are deprecated? I just used it